# Testing Soap Consumer. 'uri' must not be empty

Tags: kotlin, soap, mocking, spring-ws

I have a method for calling the "marshalSendAndReceive" method on sending a message over Soap.

```
class SoapConnector : WebServiceGatewaySupport() {

    fun getClient(documentId: String): Person {
        val request = getSearchRequest(documentId)

        val response = webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request) as SearchResponse

        return getPerson(response)
    }
```

I also have a configuration file.

```
@Configuration
class SearchClientConfig {


    @Bean
    fun marshaller(): Jaxb2Marshaller? {
        return Jaxb2Marshaller().apply {
            contextPath = "wsdl" //here path to generated java classes from wsdl
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun searchCilent(marshallerJaxb: Jaxb2Marshaller): SoapConnector {
        return SoapConnector().apply {
            defaultUri = "http://20.40.59.1:8080/cdi/soap/services/ServiceWS"
            marshaller = marshallerJaxb
            unmarshaller = marshallerJaxb
        }
    }
}
```

I want to Mock this method.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Sql(scripts = ["classpath:db/init.sql"])
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase(
    beanName = "dataSource",
    provider = AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase.DatabaseProvider.DOCKER
)
class SoapTest : WebServiceGatewaySupport(){

    private lateinit var webServiceGatewaySupport: WebServiceGatewaySupport

    private lateinit var connector: SoapConnector


    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        webServiceGatewaySupport = Mockito.mock(WebServiceGatewaySupport::class.java)
    }

    @Test
    fun getClientTest() {

        Mockito.`when`(webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(ArgumentMatchers.anyObject())).thenReturn(SearchResponse())

        connector.getClient(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(7))

    }

}
```

But there is a bug:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'uri' must not be empty
```

I don't understand what the problem is and I don't know how to make a working Mock of this method.